# How can I force calls to some constructors/functions to use named arguments?

Tags: kotlin, named-parameters

I have some constructors and functions that I'd like to always be called with named arguments. Is there a way to require this?

I'd like to be able to do this for constructors and functions with many parameters and for those that read more clearly when named arguments are used, etc.

Comment: Relevant Kotlin bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-14934

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In Kotlin 1.0 you can do this by using [`Nothing`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html) from the stdlib.

In Kotlin 1.1+ you will get "Forbidden vararg parameter type: Nothing" but you can replicate this pattern by defining your own empty class with a private constructor (like `Nothing`), and using that as the first varargs parameter.

```
/* requires passing all arguments by name */
fun f0(vararg nothings: Nothing, arg0: Int, arg1: Int, arg2: Int) {}
f0(arg0 = 0, arg1 = 1, arg2 = 2)    // compiles with named arguments
//f0(0, 1, 2)                       // doesn't compile without each required named argument

/* requires passing some arguments by name */
fun f1(arg0: Int, vararg nothings: Nothing, arg1: Int, arg2: Int) {}
f1(arg0 = 0, arg1 = 1, arg2 = 2)    // compiles with named arguments
f1(0, arg1 = 1, arg2 = 2)           // compiles without optional named argument
//f1(0, 1, arg2 = 2)                // doesn't compile without each required named argument
```

It also works in Kotlin 1.7 with `Nothing`, but it's necessary to suppress the compilation error:

```kotlin
...
@Suppress("FORBIDDEN_VARARG_PARAMETER_TYPE", "UNUSED_PARAMETER")
vararg nothings: Nothing,
...
```

As `Array<Nothing>` is illegal in Kotlin, a value for `vararg nothings: Nothing` can't be created to be passed in (short of reflection I suppose). This seems a bit of a hack though and I suspect there is some overhead in the bytecode for the empty array of type `Nothing` but it appears to work.

This approach does not work for data class primary constructors which cannot use `vararg` but these can be marked as `private` and secondary constructors can be used with `vararg nothings: Nothing`.

Comment: While this was never intended by the design of the language, I applaud your ingenuity :)

Comment: You can spread an array of Nothing with *arrayOf<Nothing>(). Or you should be able to, I think

Comment: @Deanveloper I just tried it out. I get: "Unsuppored [Array<Nothing> in return type is illegal" and "Cannot use 'Nothing' as reified type parameter". Even if you could, the subsequent arguments in, for example, `f0(*arrayOf<Nothing>(), 0, 1, 2)` are combined with the contents of the spread array which causes a different error: "The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Nothing".

Comment: Not working in Kotlin `1.3.72`, says Nothing is forbidden type for vararg

Comment: @DimaRostopira see note about 1.1+, I've moved it up in the answer to clarify, you'll need to create your own version of `Nothing` (and you can call it whatever you'd like, e.g. `Forbidden`)

Comment: @mfulton26 missed it, sorry)

Comment: What I really want is an annotation or similar that causes IntelliJ to always add names to calls to that method automatically.

Comment: sounds like a good feature request to make to me