How to prevent arguments passed in incorrect order by mistake
Code base is in Java. I need to read data from two different stores conditionally.
interface Reader<T> {
  T read();
}

T foo(Reader<T> reader1, Reader<T> reader2) {
    // read using reader1 or reader2 based on some
    // conditions
}

ConcreType1 readFromDB1(some parameters) {
}

ConcreType2 readFromDB2(some other parameters) {
}

void someMethod() {
  // some logic
  foo(
   () -> readFromDB1(params1), // 1
   () -> readFromDB2(params2), // 2
   );

}

If developer switch order above parameters 2, 1. code will compile and it will just do read from incorrect DB. it may fail at runtime if data is missing or format is different. I want it to fail at compile time.
I tried bunch of things - like creating two interfaces, but does not help. passing dummy parameter on one interface etc, either it did not work or code looked overly complex and hard to read. How do I prevent developer accidentally switch order of parameters? Seeking recommendations.

This sounds like a job for automated testing.  (unit tests, integration tests, etc.)  I don't see how one would fail this at compile time since the code is syntactically valid.

You can force foo to be callable only with named parameters: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/37394267/13963086

If you're choosing to read from either reader1 or reader2 already based on some conditions, why would the order of the parameters matter? Is it a matter of choosing one over the other (e.g. assigning some kind of "priority" to them)?

@Rogue Order matter because reader1 become reader2 and vice-versa.

@David good thought, I will think more if its feasible in our system

Whoever you are voting this down, if you built any real system, you would know how genuine this problem is and how hard to solve it. Why would you not ask clarification?

I would probably wrap either set of parameters into a parameter object. You can commonly define them in an ancestor, but have readfromDB1 and readfromDB2 only accept either of two empty subclasses.

Problem is that parameters may change, current Reader interface handles such cases

Something like this might work for you?...
T foo(Reader<T> reader1, Reader<T> reader2) {
    Reader<T> readerA, Reader<T> readerB;
    if( reader1.getKnownParameter() == knownParameterValue ) {
       readerA = reader1;
       readerB = reader2;
    }
    else {   
       readerA = reader2;
       readerB = reader1;
    }
    ....
}


Thanks, only one method can be overridden using lambda expression. so getKnownParameter() or read(). we need to find some other way to get signal which one is which. Good idea though
